# Loop through Excel Ranges Filling Combobox VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, loops, combobox, iteration

I have a program that needs to iterate through a very large excel range, to combine two ranges into one combo box value. I have the following code to do so, but all it does is iterate the first value five times. If I remove the first FOR loop, then it simply only returns the first value and never completes. Any suggestions on what I can do to polish this code up and get it working?

```
        Dim i As Integer
    If TenantBox.SelectedItem = "CNS" Then
        WFMBook.Workbooks.Open("C:\Schedule.xlsx")
        For i = 0 To 5 Step +1
            For Each CNSCell In WFMBook.Range("A3:A1441").Cells
                f = CNSCell.Value.ToString
            Next
            For Each tst In WFMBook.Range("B3:B1441").Cells
                l = tst.Value.ToString
            Next
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(f + " " + l)
            If (i = 5) Then
                Exit For
            End If
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You put ComboBox1.Items.Add....in a wrong place. This would add only the last f value

Comment: Where would add it? I've tried numerous places to similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, just change  the x to  1 if VBA is 1 based.

```
If TenantBox.SelectedItem = "CNS" Then
        WFMBook.Workbooks.Open("C:\XHSchedule.xlsx")
            Dim colCount = WFMBook.Range("A3:A8").Cells.Count
        For x = 1 To colCount Step +1
            For Each CNSCell In WFMBook.Range("A3:A8").Cells
                f = WFMBook.Range("A3:A8").Cells(x).Value.ToString
                l = WFMBook.Range("B3:B8").Cells(x).Value.ToString
            Next
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(f + " " + l)
        Next
                End If
```

Comment: Strangely, if I do it this way, it simply freezes and never completes. I've tried lowering the size of the range it iterates over to eliminate that as a cause, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Edit: Size of range is what is what is causing it.

Comment: Well you need to refine your question more like providing the data you looping into and some output expected

Comment: OK, here's what's going on now. Basically, I'm pulling first and last names, combining them into one, and adding them into a combo box. Range size appears to be what was causing the freeze. Eliminating that for now, what happens with your suggested code is everyone has the same last name. So, the A value is updating and looping properly, but not the B value.

Comment: I have a suggestion. Excel provide a named range Just search it in the internet, This is where  you can name firstname  + lastname column name with one range name. that way you can reference it only as one range like WFMBook.Range("Fullname") and not WFMBook.Range("'A3:A1441')

Comment: Here's a named range link for you http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2011-01-15-excel-range-name-overview.htm

Comment: And for looping named range using VBA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039437/loop-through-cells-in-named-range

Comment: The code is almost perfect. Only one problem, now it returns each value five times, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why. It should not be.

Edit -- Fixed it. Will post correct revised code shortly.

Comment: I edited your code you don't need this For i = 0 To 5 Step +1 'You dont need this --> it's causing to loop five times :D