# Loop Through a Named Range to Copy and Paste the data

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to automate the copy and paste of data from a range (T3:AH3) on sheet "CMJ" that is generated by selecting a name in a named range (Unique_Names), on the same sheet.  The paste will occur in a data table on "DataSheet" in the bottom most row, and paste only as text.

I have little exeperience with VBA and I have tried various lines of code, and below has worked the best so far.  However, when I run the code below it copy and pastes the first name from the list about 50 times, and never loops through the rest of the names.

```
Sub LoopandCopy()

Sheets("CMJ").Select

Dim x As Range

For Each x In Sheets("CMJ").Range("Unique_Names")

    Range("T3:AH3").Copy

    Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome. As others have done before you, it may be more productive to settle the mechanics of looping through a range before you move on to more complicated tasks. Your research might have noted [loop through cells in named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039437/loop-through-cells-in-named-range) which gives a detailed discussion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop through cells in named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039437/loop-through-cells-in-named-range)

Comment: I will read through that post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, written on phone. If I understand correctly, you want to copy the range `"T3:AH3"` on sheet `CMJ` and paste to a particular row on sheet `DataSheet`.

```
Sub LoopandCopy()

With thisworkbook

    Dim rangeToCopy as range
    Set rangeToCopy = .worksheets("CMJ").Range("T3:AH3")

    With .worksheets("DataSheet")

        Dim rowToPasteTo as long
        rowToPasteTo = .Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

        .cells(rowToPasteTo, "A").resize(rangeToCopy.rows.count, rangetocopy.columns.count).value2 = rangetocopy.value2

    End with

End with

End sub
```

Instead of copy-pasting, the above assigns one range's values to another range (of identical size).

Comment: This is impressive for a phone solution - I'll indent for you if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

## Fast Loop & Copy

I'm guessing here that the unique values are in one column.

**Put this into the CMJ Sheet Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private TargetValue As Variant

Sub LoopandCopy()

  Const cSource As Variant = "CMJ"              ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cTarget As Variant = "DataSheet"        ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrUnique As String = "Unique_Names"   ' Named Range
  Const cStrSource As String = "T3:AH3"         ' Source Range
  Const cTargetColumn As Variant = "A"          ' Column Letter/Number

  Dim i As Long             ' Named Range Cells Counter
  Dim lngLastRow As Long    ' Target Last Row
  Dim vntSource As Variant  ' Source Array

  ' Calculate Target Last Row.
  lngLastRow = Worksheets(cTarget).Cells(Rows.Count, cTargetColumn) _
      .End(xlUp).Row

  With Worksheets(cSource)

    ' Paste Source Range into Source Array.
    vntSource = .Range(cStrSource)

    For i = 1 To .Range(cStrUnique).Cells.Count
      ' Resize the cell at the intersection of Target Last Row and
      ' Target Column by the size of Source Array.
      Worksheets(cTarget).Cells(lngLastRow + i, cTargetColumn) _
          .Resize(, UBound(vntSource, 2)) = vntSource
    Next

  End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Worksheets("CMJ").Range("N7"), Target) Is Nothing Then
      If Target.Value <> TargetValue Then LoopandCopy
      TargetValue = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, all the "Unique_Names" are names, and they are located in cells "J63:J68", but the data validation list that must be changed to in order to change the data that needs to be copied is in cell "N7".  Maybe that is the part I missed in the explanation.  If the name in cell N7 does not change then the data to select and copy doesn't change.  Is there a way "loop" and go to the next name in N7 in order to change the data and then copy/paste then repeat?  Side note, I used your code and it did the same as mine, copied the same name 50 times.

Comment: I change it manually, which updates the data and then I copy and paste to the other sheet.  I do not have a formula to scroll through the list and change the names

Comment: Ok, so we have to use the change event to trigger the sub. Gimme 10 min. But tell me why are you looping through the unique values? There are 50 of them, that's why you get 50 rows. Don't you want only one row?

Comment: Okay.  The name that is shown generates the data that I want to copy and paste.  This data is generated through a series of other formulas that draws numbers from a sheet separate, not relevant to the VBA code. The unique names lists, could contain up to 30 people and I need a faster way to generate the data I need and copy it to the data sheet than manually clicking through the data validation list and then copy/paste the generated data. Yes, I only want one row for each name, that is my goal.

Comment: You mean I don't have to loop through the unique values?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit.  Yes I need to loop through the names.  because each name will generate a different set of data that i need, but i only want one row for each name to be copied and pasted. But the size of the list of names may change, based on how many people are on a given team

Comment: @Matt H: You're looping through the unique values but they aren't incorporated in the loop. They have to be somehow 'mentioned' there or else it is 50 entries in vain. You have to figure out the condition something like if a cell contains the current unique value then do something. You are all the time copying T3:AH3. What's so important in that range? And what do you mean by when a unique value is selected? How is it selected?