# How do I declare a GroupBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to group some Option Buttons, several groups on a sheet.  This code adds group boxes and works until I set Option Explicit On.  There is no declaration for GroupBoxes, I tried

```
Dim gb As GroupShapes
```

but get a Type Mismatch.  I am a rookie at VBA, thank you in advance.

```
'add GroupBox
    pp = (myRow + 1 + ExamData(i, 7) - 1)
    gbRange = "B" + Trim(Str(myRow + 1)) + ":B" + Trim(Str(pp))
    Set vvv = ws.Range(gbRange)
    Set gb = ws.GroupBoxes.Add(vvv.Left, vvv.Top, vvv.Width, vvv.Height)
    With gb
        .caption = ""
        .Name = "gb" + Trim(Str(i))
    End With
```

I also tried using:

```
ws.Shapes.Range(vvv).Group
```

but I am getting  "the index into the specific collection is out of bounds"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54234047/1521579

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I had seen this and started to use it but when I saw that GroupBox does not show in the quickmenu I talked myself out of trying it.