# Loop to copy individual lines from one worksheet to other

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to write a makro that takes data from 2 different worksheets and copies them into one table in a 3rd, new, worksheet.

the code should copy A36:D36 from WS1, paste it into A1:D1 on WS3, then take A1:H1 from WS2 and post it into E1:L1 on WS3. (i got that far at least). in what is then WS3.L1 there's a number which corresponds to a number in a column in row 34 of WS1. i'd like to then copy the cell from WS1 where the row I just copied intersects with the column that has the number that is in (e.g. in the first case row36 and column xy).

then it should take the same range again from WS1, but offset the range on WS2 by 1 row (i.e. combine row 1 of WS1 with row 2 of WS2). it should repeat that until there is no row left in WS2. then, it should offset the range in WS1 by one line and do the whole thing again. Ws1 has 150 lines, WS2 has 50 - in the end there should be 150*50 lines.

so far i tried Do Until loops where i defined my ranges as variables (which i haven't been able to offset) and by looping through cells in a named range (as for example here: [loop through cells in named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039437/loop-through-cells-in-named-range/13039838)) but haven't been able to get it done.

do you have any suggestions on how to make it work? thanks!

Comment: `copy the cell from WS1 where the row I just copied intersects ` copy cell to where ?

Comment: It's very helpful to include what code you have written so far in your post :)